# PDO installed but no dblib

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu

```
root@YYDream:/etc/apache2# dpkg -l |grep php5
ii  libapache2-mod-php5               5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
ii  php5                              5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
ii  php5-cgi                          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary)
ii  php5-cli                          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                       5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-curl                         5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   CURL module for php5
ii  php5-dev                          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   Files for PHP5 module development
ii  php5-gd                           5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   GD module for php5
ii  php5-mysql                        5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   MySQL module for php5
ii  php5-odbc                         5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   ODBC module for php5
ii  php5-sqlite                       5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   SQLite module for php5
ii  php5-sybase                       5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8                   Sybase / MS SQL Server module for php5
```

I install these packages on server . And the same pachages on my PC.
But after I test it.I got information below.

```
PDO drivers dblib, mysql, odbc, sqlite # this info in phpinfo() on my pc

PDO drivers mysql #this info in phpinfo() on my server
```

Well, I think I installed the same package for these two machines. But why I lose dblib on my server? Have I miss some important packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-odbc php5-sybase tdsodbc
```

`php5-sybase` will give you `dblib`, `tdsodbc` will give you `FreeTDS` and `php5-odbc` will give you `ODBC`. These will likely require other packages so just accept whatever `apt` suggests when you run the above command.

Comment: I installed php5-sybase but I haven't got dblib.

Comment: Can I use PHP5.5 or I must use PHP5.3?

Comment: @kamushin - I'm currently using PHP-5.3.10 on Ubuntu 12.04. Did you restart your webserver after installing `php5-sybase`? `sudo service apache2 restart` and then check `phpinfo()`. Did you install `php5-odbc` and 'tdsodbc` as well?

Comment: yes,I installed them, and restart apache2. I am also using PHP-5.3.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.But I still get PDO drivers mysql

Comment: when I remove the odbc, and restart apache2, I still get `PDO drivers mysql`.

Comment: @kamushin - if you execute `ls /usr/lib/php5/20090626+1fs` do you see a `pdo_dblib.so` listed? When you executed `sudo apt-get install php5-sybase` did you get any errors? You can check your logs for `apt` in `/var/log/apt/`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.
https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/php7.2-pdo-dblib

If you have multiple PHP version you can check your current PHP version in terminal with this command:

```
php --ini

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-pdo-dblib
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-pdo-dblib
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3-pdo-dblib
```

Don't forget to restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For sqlsrv drivers read this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15

**If you are using php5.6 then you can try this:**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sybase php5-odbc freetds-common
```

Refrence:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Note: Make sure the cli version of PHP and browser version of PHP is same.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `freetds-bin` and/or `freetds-bin:i386` package is installed.